# how to do lengthy operation in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am learning wordpress plugins and getting to know it fairly well.
now i think i need help doing small operation is fine but length operation how we do that. i guess AJAX or cron job

an example say i am trying to use content spinner api .so i have to send 100 post title and content to content spinner ,wait for response and update post title and content.

whats the best way to do that in wordpress plugin

Ajax where each post is sent to content spinner api and on result we update UI. please point good tutorial for that

or a cron job but i know wordpress cron job is limited

please please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to keep the user locked until the API returns the result best option would be to use a cronjob that will run a PHP script which will update all your articles. Not necessarily Wordpress cronjob because that could cause delays if the site doesn't have any traffic, you could use a system cronjob.

With AJAX you will still lock the user, if the user closes the page the API call will not be finished and the title and content won't be updated.

Depends mostly on how the plugin is going to be used. If you want to spin the content on bulk articles (100 posts at once) go with cronjob, if you want to spin the content after the user has written the article do it with AJAX or hook your plugin on [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action.

Comment: thanks i am thinking same but do with cron job i can access wordpress built in function or only core php.can you give me on very simple example

Comment: You can also access wp core function in a separate script file that will run through system cronjob. Just prepend this code in your script
`define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
global $wp, $wp_query, $wp_the_query, $wp_rewrite, $wp_did_header;
require(BASE_PATH . 'wp-load.php');`